# Twilio Trial Account does not get incoming call

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-api

I'm developing my iOS Voip Application with Twilio.

I got free trial account and am working on call from my iphone to the Voip Application(Installed to another iphone). I'm confident that the capability token I issued on my server is right though there is no way to confirm if the capability token is right or not as the issued TCDevice class in my iOS application.

The problem is, when I call from my phone to the trial phone number, the call log on console shows me warning that says "'To' phone number not verified". I'm sure 'To' phone number is the one I got on Twilio and have no way to verify it.

Does anyone know Twilio trial number can get incoming call?
Are there any ways can I confirm the capability token is right?

Thank you

Comment: What do you expect when you make the call to your Twilio number? What is the TwiML that you are using when the number receives a call?

Comment: I return TwilML like this on my server. I expect this TwiML call to my Voip application.                                                                                                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial>capability token</Dial></Response>                And I create TCDevice class in my iOS application so that it gets incoming call if I understand right?                                                                      device = TCDevice.init(capabilityToken: tokenCapability, delegate: self)

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve? If that's the TwiML that you return when that number is called, it sounds like Twilio is just avoiding an infinite loop. Can you edit your question with the current flow of your app/call and any relevant code?

Comment: May I ask you one more thing before I edit the question? If I understand right, I need to set capability token on my server side as request url when the number I got on Twilio gets called, plus I create TCDevice class with capability token I set on my server side and then the Voip application on the iphone gets incoming call. What do you mean 'Twilio is just avoiding an infinite loop' ? Does that happen in any case ?

Comment: Sorry, think I misread your last comment. Think I can answer this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You do not need to set the capability token in the `<Dial>` in your TwiML.

You need to [generate a capability token on your server](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) and setup your TCDevice object with it. The capability token should set a name for the client when you declare `allow_incoming_connections` on it: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens#allow-incoming-connections

```
from twilio.util import TwilioCapability

account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "secret"

capability = TwilioCapability(account_sid, auth_token)
capability.allow_client_incoming("tommy")
print(capability.generate())
```

Then, when you call your Twilio number, you need to use [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) with a nested [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client) with the name you set in the capability token. Like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>tommy</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Then Twilio can direct the call into your client application.

Comment: Actually call log shows the from/to number like +81xxxxxxxx and I thought it was right, but now it reflects the name I set for the client not a tel number.